# display json string if you don't know name in pair?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json object (I know, technically , it's not an `object`) but I don't know the name in the name/value pairs. How can I surface this?  I've tried something like `alert(jsonObj[0].innerHTML());` but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could `console.log(jsonObj);` and check it with firebug,etc.

Comment: This is handy if it is massive and you want the JSON laid out nicely for your review: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/prettyprint-for-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

console.log(jsonObj); in FireFox was it!  Thanks Jeemusu!